# Do mathematicians have jobs in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, economics

I'm an aspiring Mathematician i.e. a pure/applied math major with a minor in comp sci and econ.  I'm sure you star-wars fans (at least I do) fantasize what it would be like if I existed in the Star-Wars Universe.  Usually I imagine being someone else, i.e. I imagine being a jedi, sith or bounty hunter.

But this time I considered **what if I existed in the Star Wars Universe and I was me, an aspiring mathematician**.  **Do mathematicians even exist in Star Wars?**  I'm under the impression all technical jobs in Star Wars are interested solely in Technology (Engineering) and Hacking (Comp. Sci).

Comment: Why is this closed?? He asked for examples of Mathematicians in the SW universe! This is not opinion. I have an answer based on facts and examples from legends books. I want this reopened.

Comment: @Hatandboots - Please post this as a Meta.scifi.stackexchange.com question asking to re-open. And/or flag for reopen using a "flag" link under the question

Comment: Acknowledging the reopen, after the recent edits.

Comment: Nah. No one needs people that prove all kinds of convenient things are impossible.

Comment: If you're an aspiring mathematician and you cannot see how you can apply it... oh honey good luck.

Comment: @AlecTeal I was wondering if their were known mathematicians in Star Wars.  In my question it should be clear I already knew applications existed (such as engineering and comp sci), but I was wondering about pure mathematicians, i.e. doing math solely for math.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mathematitians definitely have their place in Star Wars galaxy - ironically, in capacities similar to today's earth.

- The biggest single employer for mathematicians today is <strike>No Such Agency</strike> National Security Agency.

  It employs mathematicians - to put it in layman crude terms - as code makers and code breakers.

  In Star Wars, the same exact thing happens in canon: the new Disney canon book "*Star Wars: Heir to the Jedi*" has Drusil, a member of mathematically inclined [Givin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Givin) specis. The central plot revolves around Empire trying to get her to break Rebel Alliance codes, and Rebels trying to save her from Imperials to do the reverse.
- Other mathematically inclined people get snapped up by more of an applied side of things, to become quants for financial companies and build financial models.

  In Star Wars, enter mathematically inclined [Muuns](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Muun/Legends), who were prominent in banking. They founded InterGalactic Banking Clan *(source: AotC and CW)* as well as served as a kind-of-Federal-Reseve, backing Galactic Credit *(source: "Darth Plagueis" book, EU/Legends canon)*.
- Many statistically inclined mathematicians end up doing actuarial work, especially for insurance companies.

  In Star Wars, we have no less than [**five** known insurance companies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Insurance_companies). Makes sense, with all the risks.
- Besides, think of what would happen if Star Wars universe didn't have mathematicians? **THIS**:

  [image]

Comment: Ah, awesome! In all the Star Wars I've seen (movies, some books and shows) I have not ever seen a mathematician in Star Wars so I assumed they didn't exist.

Comment: @Rashad - less canon-y: http://darth.uncyclomedia.co/wiki/Darth_Mathematician

Comment: @DVK-cool, this is the first I've seen of darth.uncyclomedia

Comment: That's from Mad magazine, isn't it? What level of canon is the Mad magazine parody of Return of the Jedi?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - Don't care. It's more funny than Jar-Jar. :)

Comment: What does it say about humanity that thirty years later I INSTANTLY recognize the Mad Magazine parody.

Comment: @Rashad you haven't seen a toilet either, have you then assumed that [nobody poops](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops)?

Comment: In fairness to Darth, they could simply move the Death Star into a higher orbit and then the days *would be* 28 hours long.

Comment: @richard days shipboard are typically regimented not local astronomical

Comment: @DVK - Fair enough. Then all you need to do is dick around with the clocks on the ship.

Comment: @richard given what R2 D2 did on ds1, that sounds vaguely dirty

Comment: @Rashad  There are no toilets nor bathrooms or beds in Star Wars movies either.... we assume they exist but are not relevant to the story.

Comment: @Criggie - The Millennium Falcon has [a bed](http://www.starwarsnewsnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Millennium-Falcon-Interior-2.png). It's even mentioned in the novelisation

Comment: @Richard "But Lord Vader, our current orbit is 14 hours long!"

Comment: @Criggie You could argue this is a (very uncomfortable) bed: http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130313220113/starwars/images/thumb/1/10/Cell_2187.png/500px-Cell_2187.png (Leia in prison cell)

Answer (score 8):

Funny that you should ask this now, I just finished reading X-Wing: Mercy Kill which deals with a Mathematician feeling out of place.

A Gamorrean male named [Voort "Piggy" saBinring](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Voort_saBinring) is a professor of mathematics at a University on some planet. 
"I'm a math instructor now. I take mathematical concepts, I shape them into spikes, and I spend months hammering them into the heads of students who's much rather be involved in amorous pursuits or playing games,..." So there are for sure professors and students of mathematics.

So there is a need for living professors rather than just having droids do the teaching, "'A teacher droid can do everything you're doing for your students...' 'A droid can't instill into them a love for mathematics'". Chapter 2 page 30ish.

As for real world job applications for mathematicians, especially with minors in comp sci., I believe there would be even more opportunities, not less.  Don't underestimate the practical applications of Mathematics. I'm a computer Engineer, so not that different from your educational background, and I see math EVERYWHERE. There's not a day that goes by where I don't use calculus, or at least some form of math, in technical designs. We often use mathematicians as consultants for some of the more complex problems. IMO in a world full of starships, droids, and battle stations, mathematicians would never be out of the job.

There are also countless examples of scientists/mathematicians in many SW video games. They usually design advanced technologies however.

As a side note, Engineers often work side by side with mathematicians and other scientists in the real world.

Comment: Awesome. I knew I should have prioritized reading mercy kill

Comment: In addition, I think in the films and TV series there are several references to performing complex calculations when jumping into hyperspace.